# Non animatable properties within keyframes are ignored on iOS

Tags: ios, css, css-animations

I understand that non-animatable properties are not interpolated within animations, however, my understanding is that the values are at least (abruptly) computed.

So, for example, let's say I want to 'animate' the overflow property (which is not animatable, i.e. [not in this list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)) from `hidden` to `visible` - I would expect that the computed value will change appropriately.

(I tried looking in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/) for this but couldn't find it mentioned explicitly)

This is actually what happens in Chrome and Firefox, but not on iOS.(Safari, iPhone)

```css
.animate {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: 3s resetOverflow;
}
@keyframes resetOverflow {
  from {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: red;
  }
  to { 
    overflow: visible;
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animate">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in </div>
```

### [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/mmVWxr?editors=1100#0)

Notice that on Chrome and Firefox the value for overflow changes from hidden to visible, however on **iOS** the values for overflow seem to be completely ignored - keeping its default value of visible.

### **NB:**

1)  I added animation for the *color* just to show that **animatable properties are working fine** in iOS

2) It does seem that iOS ignores all non-animatable properties (not just overflow) - here's [another demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/bWwpKY) which tries to animate the `position` property.

3) I know that this can be done with javascript - [demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/JNRKdG).... but I would like to do this with CSS.

Is this a bug in iOS? Any workarounds?

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. The interpolation rules are in css-transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying browser prefixes as per following answers:

[CSS3 animation not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari)

[keyframe animation does not work on safari for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745152/keyframe-animation-does-not-work-on-safari-for-ios)

```css
.animate {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: 3s resetOverflow;
  animation: 3s resetOverflow;
}

@-webkit-keyframes resetOverflow {
  from {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: red;
  }
  to {
    overflow: visible;
    color: green;
  }
}

@keyframes resetOverflow {
  from {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: red;
  }
  to {
    overflow: visible;
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animate">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, browsers prefixes are not the issue here. Note that the color property changes, but not the overflow property. (on iOS - safari, iphone etc)