# CSS style "position" is not work in keyframes on IOS

Tags: jquery, ios, css, html, animation

I use animation in css.

I am trying to move a `div` to the top of the page with animation.

The following example code works in Google Chrome and Android.

It does not work on iOS11.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>animate</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            .content-wrapper {
                width:100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .card-wrapper {
                height: 30rem;
                width: 100%;
            }
            @keyframes moveToTop {
                0% { position: absolute; top: 30rem; }
                100% { position: absolute; top: 0rem; }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes moveToTop {
                0% { position: absolute; top: 30rem; }
                100% { position: absolute; top: 0rem; }
            }

            .ntc { 
                animation: moveToTop 3s;
                -webkit-animation: moveToTop 3s;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="font-size: 16px">
        <div class='content-wrapper'>
            <div class='card-wrapper nrc' style='background-color: red'>
                <div class='card'>
                    A
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='card-wrapper ntc' style='background-color: black'>
                <div class='card'>
                    B
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This solution does not work for me:

[keyframe animation does not work on safari for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745152/keyframe-animation-does-not-work-on-safari-for-ios)

I tried:

```
 -webkit-animation-name: movToTop; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
```

instead of

```
-webkit-animation: moveToTop 3s;
```

That did not work.

When I move the `position:absolute;` out of the keyframes, it works. But I have to put `position:absolute;` in the keyframes block.

Comment: "It does not work" is not a problem description that is likely to get you useful answers.

Comment: What happens when you use only rems or pixels.

Comment: @RauliRajande It does not work when only use rems or pixels. I edit the question, only use rems.

Comment: In here people say, that in ios, non-animatable properties (including position) are completely ignored in keyframes. You have to define these in normal css: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498896/non-animatable-properties-within-keyframes-are-ignored-on-ios

Comment: @RauliRajande The reference you provide solved my problem，I use js to change the position before/after animation start/end，hope IOS can fixed it if it really a bug. Thank you.